# TFF : ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None,) are incompatible

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I use TFF and My dataset has a binary_mode class,  this is how I declared my inputs :

```
genv0 = img_genv.flow_from_directory(pathv0,(224, 224),'rgb', batch_size=2, class_mode='binary')
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(genv0, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), output_shapes = ([2,224,224,3],[2,1])
```

Here is my sample_batch :

```
images, labels = next(img_gen.flow_from_directory(path0,target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=2, class_mode='binary'))
```

and I add this layer in my model

```
model_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(last_layer)
 model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001)
             loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=([tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()))
```

When running my code, I find this error :

```
 ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None,) are incompatible
```

I think the problem is that sample_batch does not take label with bainary mode.
How can I resolve this problem
Thanks

Comment: Can you print the shapes of `images` and `labels` from t he sample batch?

Answer (score 1):

From its name, it seems like in binary mode the label may be a scalar `1` or `0` with shape `[`], rather than a tensor `[1]` or `[0]`. Keras generally likes tensors.

Perhaps try a [`tf.reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) or [`tf.expand_dims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) to turn scalars into tensors. If `labels` is shape `[batch_size]`, we want to turn that into shape `[batch_size, 1]` with:

```py
labels = tf.reshape(labels, shape=[-1, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I edit the question and I add tf.data.dataset where I make output_shapes, So where and hiow I must add your suggestion ?

Comment: This will depend on where in the code is the error being raised. Could the question be extended to include the code that creates and runs the training process and the stack trace included with the error message?